# Built a custom file in XML, Can't call it in Java by any means

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am working on ListViews. I decided to make a customized listview. For it, definitely another xml file (customized) is required. I built it but I just cannot call it by any means in java. Look the following line as row_layout is always RED with error "Cannot Resolve Symbol "row_layout":

```
ListAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.row_layout, cars);
```

Following is code of my customized xml file row_layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/row_layout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/myTextView1"
            android:textSize="32dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Following is my Java file code :

```
package com.ranatalha.mylistapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String [] cars=
                {
                "Mehran",
                "Corolla",
                "Faw v2",
                "Honda City"
                };

        //to link my above created array with in a list
        //ListAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cars);

        ListAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.row_layout, cars);

        //referring the listview createdin xml
        ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistView);

        //connecting listview with adapter
        mylistview.setAdapter(myadapter);

        //Catching clicks on listview
        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    //implements method
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        String CarsPicked = "Your Picked The Car: " + String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, CarsPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
         }
         );
         }
         }
```

Comment: `android.R` accesses the resource of the operating system. If you want to use your own custom layout you have to import R of your app. `android.R.layout.row_layout` should be `R.layout.row_layout`

Comment: @Blackbelt Hey man, you are best. Was struggling with this short thing for an hour. It was so simple. Thankyouuuuu :)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.R` uses built in android resources. Try `android.R.layout.simple_list_item1`.

Or create your own layout and call its ID from `R.layout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VikingPingvin, your suggestion also worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android.R.layout.row_layout` we should use `R.layout.row_layout` because android.R access the resources of the OS whereas R can help in importing custom layouts. Thanks to @BlackBelt for helping me in the comments section above :)